# Can I use Perl-regular expressions in SAS to add imputations to date?

Tags: regex, sas

For context I'm a SAS programmer in clinical trials but I have this spec for variable ADTC.

> If EC.ECDTC contains a full datetime, set ADTMC to the value of EC.ECDTC in "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm" format. If EC.ECDTC contains a full or partial date but no time part then set ADTMC to the date part of EC.ECDTC in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. In both cases, replace any missing elements of the format with "XX", for example "2022-01-01 16:XX" or "2022-01-XX"

So currently I'm using this piece of code which is partially fine but not ideal

```
 check=count(ecdtc,'-');
 if check = 0 and ~missing(ecdtc) then adtc = cats(ecdtc,"-XX-XX");
 else if check = 1 then adtc = cats(ecdtc,"-XX");
 else if check = 2 then adtc = ecdtc;
```

Is there a way I could use perl-regular expressions to have like a template of the outline of the date/datetime and have it search through the values for that column and if they don't match to add `-XX` if missing day or `-XX-XX` if missing day and month etc. I was thinking of utilising prxchange but how do you incorporate the template so it knows to add `-XX` in the correct position where applicable.

Comment: *Is there a way?* Yes. Usually it is expected if you have a Perl question, that you write Perl code and ask questions about that. Regexes are usually created based on the expected input, and you have no such.

Comment: @TLP It's not Perl (it's a language with Perl-like regex). It was a mistag that has been fixed.

Comment: so basically "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm" as the template and then checking each occurrence if it matches and if it doesn't to add xx where applicable

Comment: or even the inverse such as a template  value “xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx” and then use prxchange to replace the parts of the date where there is values.

Comment: Are both variables character strings?  Do you need to worry about strings that are non-empty, but not valid dates, such as 2022-20-45 ?

Comment: Why? What is wrong with the current method?

Comment: @Tom yes both are character strings and I normally would not need to worry about invalid dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I wouldn't; regex are not faster for the most part than just straight-up checking with normal code, for simple things like this.  If you have time pressure, or thousands or millions of rows... not a good idea, just use scan.

But that said, it's certainly possible, and somewhat interesting.  We'll use PRXPOSN, which lets us iterate through the capture buffers, and "capture" each bit.  This might need some tweaking, and you might need to capture/not capture the hyphens for example, but for my data this works - if your data is different, the regex will be different (and next time, post sample data!).

```
data have;
length ecdtc $16;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 ecdtc $16.;
datalines;
2020-01-01 01:02
2020-01-02
2020-01
2020
junk
;;;;
run;


data want;
  set have;
  length adtmc $16;
  array vals[3] $;
  vals[1]='XXXX';
  vals[2]='-XX';
  vals[3]='-XX';
  _rx = prxparse('/(\d{4})(-\d{2})?(-\d{2})?( \d{2}:\d{2})?/ios');
  _rc = prxmatch(_rx,ecdtc);   *this does the matching.  Probably should check for value of _rc to make sure it matched before continuing.;
  do _i = 1 to 4;   *now iterate through the four capture buffers;
    _rt = prxposn(_rx,_i,ecdtc);
    if _i le 3 then vals[_i] = coalescec(_rt,vals[_i]);
    else timepart = _rt;  *we do the timepart outside the array since it needs to be catted with a space while the others do not, easier this way;
  end;
  
  adtmc = cats(of vals[*]);  *cat them together now - if you do not capture the hyphen then use catx ('-',of vals[*]) instead;
  if timepart ne ' ' then adtmc = catx(' ',adtmc,timepart);  *and append the timepart after.;
run;
```

Comment: Note that it's probably technically possible to do all of the construction in a PRXCHANGE, but it's far more complicated than the straightforward work here.

Comment: That looks great thank you so much. My only question is what do you do when there is partial datetime value e,g 2020-01-01 01: . In that scenario I would need 2020-01-01 01:XX to display?. I really appreciate this though that's very cool. I agree that it is harder but if you were incorporating this into a macro would you say that it has benefit or would you just stick to the more simpler approach?

Comment: That's just one more thing in the same vein as the rest, I didn't include that as I didn't see a requirement for it, but you can deal with it similarly to how I dealt with the rest, just one more capture group.

Answer (score 2):

SUBSTR on the left.

```
data want2;
   set have;
   length adtmc $16;
   if length(ecdtc) le 10 then adtmc = 'xxxx-xx-xx';
   else adtmc = 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx';
   substr(adtmc,1,length(ecdtc))=ecdtc;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely a good way to do this if it works for the incoming data (as it is supposed to...)

Comment: @Joe Thanks, the "thing" I don't get is why.  The existing data is 8601 compliant I think but adding xx breaks that.

Comment: This wouldn't be the first odd requirement I've run into... :)